# How to do date/time calculation and formatting in an awk script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file `test.txt` with multiple records as below.

```
100,200,300,08-May-2012 11:24:25
100,400,300,25-May-2012 09:24:25
```

Now I want to output the data using the following "format":

```
$1,$2,$3,$4,$4+30days,$4+60days,$4+90days
```

How can I do that using `awk`?

Comment: What have you tried?  Which variant of Unix are you using?  Do you have GNU `awk` available, for example? It makes a big difference since GNU `awk` has time manipulation functionality that other variants of `awk` do not have.

Comment: Yes i have GAWK utility.please help !!

Comment: What have you tried?  You have the tools; the manual documents how to use them; what you're trying to do is a straight-forward application of what's documented in the [`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `script.awk` file

```
function map_month(m)
{
    if (m ~ /[jJ][aA][nN]/) return 1;
    if (m ~ /[fF][eE][bB]/) return 2;
    if (m ~ /[mM][aA][rR]/) return 3;
    if (m ~ /[aA][pP][rR]/) return 4;
    if (m ~ /[mM][aA][yY]/) return 5;
    if (m ~ /[jJ][uU][nN]/) return 6;
    if (m ~ /[jJ][uU][lL]/) return 7;
    if (m ~ /[aA][uU][gG]/) return 8;
    if (m ~ /[sS][eE][pP]/) return 9;
    if (m ~ /[oO][cC][tT]/) return 10;
    if (m ~ /[nN][oO][vV]/) return 11;
    if (m ~ /[dD][eE][cC]/) return 12;
    return 0;
}
function cvt_timestamp(str,     t, a)
{
    split(str, a, /[- :]/)
    a[2] = map_month(a[2])
    #print a[3] " " a[2] " " a[1] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6]
    t = mktime(a[3] " " a[2] " " a[1] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6])
    #print t
    return t
}
function fmt_timestamp(t)
{
    return strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S", t)
}
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{
    tm = cvt_timestamp($4);
    t0 = fmt_timestamp(tm +  0 * 86400)
    t1 = fmt_timestamp(tm + 30 * 86400)
    t2 = fmt_timestamp(tm + 60 * 86400)
    t3 = fmt_timestamp(tm + 90 * 86400)
    print $1, $2, $3, t0, t1, t2, t3
}
```

There's probably a better way to do the month abbreviation to number mapping; have at it.  Using functions in `awk` is valuable just the same as it is in any other language with functions.

#### Example `data` file

```
100,200,300,08-May-2012 11:24:25
100,400,300,25-May-2012 09:24:25
100,400,300,15-Sep-2012 09:24:25
100,400,300,29-Feb-2012 09:24:25
```

#### Example output

```
$ gawk -f script.awk data
100,200,300,08-May-2012 11:24:25,07-Jun-2012 11:24:25,07-Jul-2012 11:24:25,06-Aug-2012 11:24:25
100,400,300,25-May-2012 09:24:25,24-Jun-2012 09:24:25,24-Jul-2012 09:24:25,23-Aug-2012 09:24:25
100,400,300,15-Sep-2012 09:24:25,15-Oct-2012 09:24:25,14-Nov-2012 08:24:25,14-Dec-2012 08:24:25
100,400,300,29-Feb-2012 09:24:25,30-Mar-2012 10:24:25,29-Apr-2012 10:24:25,29-May-2012 10:24:25
$
```

If you decide you want to handle switches in time zone differently, that's your prerogative; you can fix the code.